# IOS 8 AVAudioRecorder change sample fomat

Tags: swift, ios8, audio-recording

I'm building a app where one of the functions is to record a voice message I want sample format 16-bit PCM but i cant seem to get it right.
I have tried lots of diffrent settings but everytime i check the file in audacity it says 32-bit float.

This is my current recorderSettings

```
var recorderSettings = [NSObject: AnyObject]()
recorderSettings[AVFormatIDKey] = kAudioFormatALaw
recorderSettings[AVSampleRateKey] = 16000
recorderSettings[AVNumberOfChannelsKey] = 1
recorderSettings[AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey] = 16
recorderSettings[AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey] = false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i found the problem i needed kAudioFormatLinearPCM instead of kAudioFormatALaw

I tried that before but then i only checked the format with audacity and it reported back 32-bit float. but after reading Dom Bryan answer I checked it again with the file command and it reported back the correct format.

so correct config would be

```
var recorderSettings = [NSObject: AnyObject]()
recorderSettings[AVFormatIDKey] = kAudioFormatLinearPCM
recorderSettings[AVSampleRateKey] = 16000
recorderSettings[AVNumberOfChannelsKey] = 1
recorderSettings[AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey] = 16
recorderSettings[AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey] = false
```

Comment: Glad to hear you got it I apologize, I complete looked over the kAudioFormat

Comment: I m trying to use these settings too , but it 's crashing my app at method .prepareToRecord() , any ideea?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into audacity settings. It preferences 32bit for flexibility and then suggests exporting in 16bit. Your code doesn't look wrong so try messing with audacity or different program.
 Here is a link to audacity's preferences: http://audacity.sourceforge.net/onlinehelp-1.2/prefs.htm

Comment: Ok but i upload the file to a service that takes that format. when i upload it from the app i get an error but after changing to 16-bit PCM in audacity i can upload that file. but maybe audacity changes some other settings to

Comment: Hm I guess it is the AVRecorder, try something along these lines:<br/>recorderSettings[AVEncoderAVBitRateKey] = 16 or maybe even try setting <br/><br/>recorderSettings[AVEncoderAudioQualityKey] = (AVAudioQualityLow)

Comment: Thanks but i tried them already, but will try them again tomorrow just in case i had some other settings that messed it up