# How to record 16bit audio swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avaudioengine

I was implementing functionality to record and to get the audio buffer from `AVAudioEngine` and play it with player, But It is with 32 bit I need it with 16 bit with sample rate 8000 can you please suggest me what I need to to for that.

```
engine = AVAudioEngine()
guard let engine = engine, let input = engine.inputNode else {
    // @TODO: error out
    return
}

let format = input.inputFormat(forBus: 0)
input.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize:4096, format:format, block: { [weak self] buffer, when in

    guard let this = self else {
        return
    }


    if let channel1Buffer = buffer.floatChannelData?[0] {
       let test = self?.copyAudioBufferBytes(buffer)
        let stram:NSData = (self?.toNSData(PCMBuffer: buffer))!
        SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.socket.emit("talk",stram);

    }
})

engine.prepare()

do {
    try engine.start()
} catch {
    // @TODO: error out
}
```

I Try above code to record audio and its woking fine but not able to get 16bit data. I send this buffer to socket and play it in android device as well, But Not able to play it in android because it is not support 32 bit data. so please provide your suggestions.

Comment: Yes, But how can I get buffer from it, Because I need to play it just after speak, Means like phone call.

Comment: The recording is store in document directory. and after play.

Comment: But I want it play just after speak like phone call :(

Comment: Ya, you are start the recording on first click and check it second time then stop recording also and play in same method. underStand.

Comment: So that Stop and Start audio playing in Same method.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835544/ios-8-avaudiorecorder-change-sample-fomat help at all?

I don't know how much this helps you now, but what you want to do seems to get built-in methods in iOS11 (see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioengine , everything with the BETA tag)